# How to use Charting`ScaledTicks?

Tags: plotting, undocumented, ticks

I found several topics about the undocumented `ScaledTicks` function and tried to use this. Here is the first example:

```
g1 = Plot[Sin[3 x] Exp[-x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All];
g2 = Plot[Sin[3 x] Exp[1.1 x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All];
{pr1, pr2} = (PlotRange[#][[2]] & /@ {g1, g2});
Show[{g1, g2 /. Line[x_] :> 
 Line[({#[[1]], Rescale[#[[2]], pr2, pr1]} &) /@ x]}, 
 Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"], 
   Charting`ScaledTicks[{Rescale[#, pr2, pr1] &, Rescale[#, pr1, pr2] &}]},
   {Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"], Automatic}}]
```

This gives a mess of second y-axis ticks:

[image]

But if we use the "full" form of `ScaledTicks`:

```
Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear", {Rescale[#, pr2, pr1] &, Rescale[#, pr1, pr2] &}, "Nice"]
```

We see a very nice picture:

[image]

So, the first question: should we always use "full" form of `ScaledTicks` even if there is no transformation of coordinates?

The second example is about `LogPlot` and similar functions.

```
Show[{LogPlot[x, {x, 1, 100}], Plot[x Log[100]/100, {x, 1, 100}]}, 
Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks["Log"], 
Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear", {#/100 Log[100] &, # 100/Log[100] &}, 
"Nice"]}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

and the result:

[image]

Here, I make all rescaling "by hand" for this simple case. If we change `ScaledTicks` to its "short" form

```
Charting`ScaledTicks[{#/100 Log[100] &, # 100/Log[100] &}]
```

The picture will be the same. So, in this example, the "short" and "full" forms of `ScaledTicks` are equivalent. How can we explain the difference between examples?

And the final observation. Any change from the simplest form `ScaledTicks["Log"]` gives errors, i.e. we can't write even `ScaledTicks["Log",{#&, #&}, "Nice"]`.

Comment: Would be good to see this answered by those who are familiar. Posting to bump this.

Comment: @kglr do you have a good answer for this? I just found how to use the `TicksLength` option to set the major and minor tick lengths using some syntax from an answer you updated recently using this function.

Comment: Please share a link to its documentation.