# Why do the frame ticks disapear when a plot is exported as PNG?

Tags: plotting, export, ticks

I am using  M12.0.0.0 on Ubuntu and I have these two plots:

```
plot1 = DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 4}, PlotPoints -> 80];
plot2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True];
```

when I export these plots as png the `FramTicks` disapear!
here is `plot1` as seen in the MMA notebook

[image]
and this how it looks when exported using `Export["/.../plotq1.png", plot1,ImageResolution -> 500]`
[image]

same thing also applies for `plot2` in the notebook is like

[image]

and exported is like

[image]

Comment: Is this a bug or the nature of PNG exporting?  The current set of answers give nice workarounds but it would be nice to see an answer to the question "why?"

Comment: @bobthechemist I think this has to do with the fact that the default ticks are defined at an absolute size, rather than as Scaled objects. When the size of the image is increased, either through `ImageSize` in a notebook, or by exporting at high resolution, the default ticks do not scale accordingly and end up too small to be seen.

Comment: @MarcoB thanks for commenting - I've seen this issue a number of times in my own work and your analysis makes sense and is helpful.

Comment: I've run into similar issues exporting figures to .png format.  My current solution is to export them to .pdf.  If you really need .png, you could always use ImageMagick to convert pdf to png.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same issue in

```
$Version
"11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"

plt1a = DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 4}, PlotPoints -> 80]
```

[image]

```
Export["plot1A.png", plt1a, ImageResolution -> 500]
```

[image]

If you specify a lower image resolution the issue does not arise:

```
Export["plot1A100.png", plt1a, ImageResolution -> 100]
```

[image]

To get the ticks visible at high image resolution, you can make the ticks longer and/or thicker:

```
plt1b = DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 4}, PlotPoints -> 80,
   FrameTicksStyle -> Thick, 
   FrameTicks -> Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, 
    "TicksLength" -> {0.02, 0.01}]]
```

[image]

```
Export["plot1B.png", plt1b, ImageResolution -> 500]
```

[image]

To get tick labels on the bottom and left frames only, use

```
FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, 
    "TicksLength" -> {0.02, 0.01}], Automatic},
  {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, 
   "TicksLength" -> {0.02, 0.01}], Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @kglr! is it possible to remove numbers from the top and right axes?

Comment: @HD2006, please see the update.

Comment: @kglr I've seen you use ``Charting`ScaledTicks` ` often. In fact, I've learned quite a few tricks with it from your answers! There is information about this function scattered through MMA.SSE, but not collected in a single place. There is, however, an unanswered question from last year ([How to use Charting`ScaledTicks?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/170314/27951)) about it that would make for a great repository of that information. I was wondering if you could be persuaded to summarize your knowledge of this function in an answer there?

Comment: @MarcoB , what I know  about ``Charting`ScaledTicks`` is limited to what I could decipher from ``??Charting`ScaledTicks``. I will see if I can extract something (perhaps a list of argument patterns) useful for the linked question.

Answer (score 5):

If you specify the FrameTicks as follows it works fine:

```
ft[low_, high_] :=
  Table[{i, i, {.01, 0}, Directive[Black, Thickness[.002]]}, {i, low,high}];

plot1 = DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 4}, PlotPoints -> 80
   , FrameTicks -> { {ft[0, 4], None}, {ft[-2, 2], None}}];

Export["/tmp/plotq1.png", plot1, ImageResolution -> 500];

SystemOpen@"/tmp/plotq1.png"
```

Comment: Nice solution, kinda frustrating that a program with a $1480/year license cost has so many quirky behaviors and poorly documented solutions.